# Can NodeJS be used on the web instead of the command-line

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, command-line

When developing a website and doing some server-side stuff with NodeJS can NodeJS be used on the command-line only or can it be used for scripting too? For example creating a script and doing all my NodeJS stuff in there and then including the script in my HTML without the command-line or is this not possible?

Comment: Why would you want to include server-side stuff in your html? I'm confused by your question

Comment: @MikeBell Like with PHP you can run the PHP inside tags. Can you run Node.js also inside JavaScript scripts without the command-line?

Comment: Look at it this way: Node.js allows you to run Javascript on the server. It's weird to ask if it's possible to run Node.js in the browser.

Comment: Your question is confusing but maybe this is what you want:  https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit

Comment: You don't really "run PHP" inside of PHP tags. PHP scans over your HTML and does its magic before sending the compiled HTML to the client.

Comment: @MikeBell Ok well that's what I mean with Node.JS

Comment: @JacquesMarais glad to help :) and if you found that useful then you'll need this for sure (very very informative and not boring to watch either lol) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkb_x9ZN0Vo

Comment: That's kind of what Node does out of the box. I'm not convinced that you know what you're after. But anyway, you said you found what you were looking for, so best of luck to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't embed Node.js in a webpage, but browsers have built in JavaScript runtimes so you don't need to embed another one.

You can't use Node.js specific APIs from JavaScript in a webpage. Most of them have serious security implications (such as providing a means for JavaScript to access the filesystem).

You can use Node.js to run an HTTP server, which you can then access from the browser (both directly and via XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Well you CAN use the APIs from JS, just not directly...you would have to send a request from the client page and have a dedicated handler on the Node.js server for each use.  But I know what you mean.  I'm not arguing against your logic, just giving a roundabout way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

try `node-browserify` @ https://github.com/substack/node-browserify, which i guess a bit closer to what you wanted here.